# setBoldweight is not working

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I was trying to add some styles to the excel sheet, I have generated using apache poi. Here is the code, I tried to make the first row in BOLD.

```
    SXSSFWorkbook wb=new SXSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excelx");

    Row row= sheet.createRow((short)0);
    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("SRNum");
    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Name");         
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    Font f = wb.createFont();
    f.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 20);
    f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    cs.setFont(f);
    row.setRowStyle(cs);
```

But still, the first row is not changing to BOLD.

Comment: IIRC, the row style won't apply to cells with content in - what happens if you also set that style on your cells as well?

Comment: You said it @Gagravarr: Thanks a lot. I have changed the code as per you commented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the valuable comment of Gagravarr, I have changed the code:

```
         Row rowhead= sheet.createRow((short)0);
         Font f = wb.createFont();
         f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
         CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
         cs.setFont(f);

         Cell cell;             
         cell = rowhead.createCell((short) 0);
         cell.setCellValue("SRNum");
         cell.setCellStyle(cs);

         cell = rowhead.createCell((short) 1);
         cell.setCellValue("Name");
         cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

Comment: Note, `Font.setBoldweight` was deprecated in 3.15 and removed in 3.17. You should use `Font.setBold` instead.